# Airflow Executor

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm still fairly new to using airflow. I have a few dags scheduled to run but they run sequentially. I want them to start running in parallel to each other. So let's say I have a task scheduled to run at 1 pm and another task to run at 2pm. If the first tasks isn't done, by 2pm, I still want the 2pm task to start running and allow the 1pm task to keep going as well.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-executors-explained/, you should use **LocalExecutor** if you want to run more than a single task at any point-in-time.

Comment: I tried switching from 'SequentialExecutor' to 'LocalExecutor' in the airflow.cfg file. However, when I tried restarting the srever. It gives me an error '(code = exited, status = 1/FAILURE)'

Comment: You will need to create a database in Postgres or Mysql for LocalExecutor to work. Check this link https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/initialize-database.html